# problem with perl format and utf data

Tags: perl, format

I am using a perl format to print out lines to a file

ie.

```
format REPORT1 =
@<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<  ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  @>>>>>       @>>>>>       @>>>>>    @>>>>>       @>>>>>
$write_student_number,  $write_serial, $write_name, $write_attempted, $write_correct, $write_score, $write_percent_correct, $write_percent_score
~~                    ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                      $write_name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
```

I retrieve the $write_name from an oracle database that is using uft8 character set.

This data use to work fine until we converted the feeding database to uft8 as well. I'm not sure what it use to be, but it was not utf 8.

The format now gives lines such as (notice the << >> and @’s)

```
009999990  000000133  Anderson, Charlie                                       30           25           25      83.3         83.3

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

009999951  000000132  Smith, Josée                                            29>>         21   @>>>    21>>>   70.0    @>>  70.0

                      ,

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

009999934  000000131<<Quiring, Randy                                     <<    30@>>>>>     12           12 @>>  40.0>
```

Instead of

```
009999990  000000133  Anderson, Charlie                                        30           25           25      83.3         83.3

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

009999951  000000132  Smith, Josée                                            29           21           21      70.0         70.0

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

009999934  000000131  Quiring, Randy                                           30           12           12      40.0
```

I tried using a bunch of different solutions I found on the web, but none worked.

```
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) );

use Encode;
use Encode 'is_utf8';

$first_name = decode_utf8($first_name);
```

I also tried

```
use Encode 'from_to';
from_to($write_name, "utf-8", "iso-8859-1");

open my $fh, ">:utf8", $filename
    or die "could not open $filename: $!\n";
```

and

```
from_to($write_name, "utf-8", "WINDOWS-1252");
```

which sort of works, except it just replaces the utf characters with `?`s.

A solution found that does sorta work is if I print out the string to a file, then read the string back in to the file and store it in the variable again.

Just a note, the format works in a windows environment. The problem only happens in unix.

I'm hoping you have a better solution.

Comment: You've posted some things that may not apply, I'd suggest removing some clutter there. However, what I'd actually like to see more of is how you're putting data into the database, and how you're getting data out, because that's likely the problem. UTF-8 is just a string of bytes wherein there can be multibyte characters. Something must be mangling the encoding of the multibyte portions, either the lead char, or the ones following but within the multibyte chars.

Comment: Is the UTF-8 flag on in the data returned by Oracle, or is it off?  Did you `binmode` the output stream explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Use of format is discouraged due to its API being flat out crazy, you may want to work with Template::Toolkit instead.

Comment: The data is retrieved using standard DBI. $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$ODS_DB",$ODS_ADPCOS_ID,$ODS_ADPCOS_PSWD) or die "Die on connect" ;

Comment: The data is retrieved using standard perl DBI

$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$ODS_DB",$ODS_ADPCOS_ID,$ODS_ADPCOS_PSWD) 
     or die "Die on connect" ;

$sql = "select write_name" .
 "from person " .
 " where person.id = " .
 "'". $student_number ."'";   
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or 
           die print STDERR "Could not prepare statement: $sql\n database error: $DBI::errstr" ;
$sth->execute() or die print  STDERR  "Unable to execute: $sth\n database error: $DBI::errstr" ;  
($write_name) = $sth->fetchrow_array;

Comment: #Writting to the file
open(REPORT1,">>$report_file") or 
    die print STDERR "Could not open output file - $report_file - $!\n" ; 

select REPORT1;
$FORMAT_LINES_PER_PAGE = $my_lines_page;
$FORMAT_PAGE_NUMBER = 0;
$FORMAT_LINES_LEFT = 0;

#Loop 

write(REPORT1); #write formated output to file

#end loop

REPORT1 is the format given above.